# Button not getting displayed after parsing the XML

Tags: android

I have an XML parser which is derived from Activity class and it parses a Button from XML.
If i create Button using Android Button API it is getting displayed on the activity. But when i create my own class for taking button attributes and display button from that class it is not getting displayed. This own class which i am creating extends LinearLayout and is unable to display.

I am calling the constructor of GuiButton class with required parameters.
Please find the code below.

```
public class GuiButton extends LinearLayout{

String label;   
int type;   
public String reqType;  
public String context;  
/**
 *  Network message for this button
 */
public String netMsg;       
/**
 * network image id for this button
 */
public String networkImageID;   
public String id;

Button btn;


public GuiButton(Context cntxt,String label,int type,String requestType,String netImgID, String id,String context,int priority,int commandType) {
    super(cntxt);



    this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);        
    btn = new Button(cntxt);
    btn.setText(label);
    addView(btn,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));            
}
```

What should i do in order to display this button on Activity? Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Do you setContentView(new GuiButton(...))? Or your linear layout is child view? In the latter case, maybe problem is in LayoutParams of GuiButton (not of btn)

Answer (score 1):

replace your constructor

```
public GuiButton(Context cntxt,String label,int type,String requestType,String netImgID, String id,String context,int priority,int commandType)
```

with

```
public GuiButton(Context cntxt, String label)
```

and set your onCreate method as mentioned bellow

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    GuiButton gb  = new GuiButton(this,"Hello");
    l.addView(gb);
}
```